# Write multiple commands in a row to WSL ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, ubuntu-16.04, wsl-2

Right now I am running a `wsl` ubunutu terminal and have a `python script` in a directory that is different to the home directory. I can get it to run a single command to it like `'ls'` but i want to `cd` in to the directory and then run the python script on `Ubuntu`.

So far I have used `subprocess.run` as well as `subprocess.popen` and both of them have gotten me the same thing which returns the base directory of of `Ubuntu`.

```
sub=subprocess.run(['wsl',"~","ls"],capture_output=True)
```

Comment: So you're running the Python script from Windows to access WSL? Why not circumvent that by running a WSL Python install?

Comment: `cd` in `subprocess` will change folder only for this process but not for `python` - you should use `import os` and `os.chdir(new_folder)` in code. BTW: instead of `ls` you can use `os.listdir()

Comment: on Linux to run many commands you can use `;` to seperate command but it needs to use `shell=True` because it needs `bash` to detect `;` . And `shell` need command as single string `subprocess.run("ls ; cd new_folder ; ls", shell=True, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

To change the directory and run the Python script, you can make use of the *os* module in Python along with *subprocess.run*. Here's a modified version of your code:
import subprocess
import os

```
# Specify the path to your target directory
target_directory = '/path/to/your/target/directory'

# Change the working directory to the target directory
os.chdir(target_directory)

# Build the command to run your Python script
command = ['wsl', 'python', 'your_script.py']

# Run the command
subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True)
```

1. ***os.chdir(target_directory)***: This changes the current working
   directory to the specified target_directory.
2. ***['wsl', 'python','your_script.py']***: This is the command to run your Python script in WSL.